# Rooting Huawei ascend G6-10 devices problem

Tags: rooting, huawei, huawei-g610s

I tried to root my Huawei H6 with `"RootGenius_en_2.2.6.exe"` in windows machine because of storage problems. But this operation interrupted in 75% and This error appeared:

```
Your phone is so solid to root!
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why! But this time I downloaded Root Genius which is [here](http://huaweinews.com/2014/10/root-ascend-g6/), and it worked! But my storage still has problem and a reset factory with backup solved my problem of storage.